# Add completely new currency to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, currency

Official currency in Iran is [Rial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_rial). But when people want to buy something they use toman which is 1/10th of rial. For example 1000 rials is 100 toman. That's why I need to add toman to list of currencies that magento has. Ib magento 1, by editing  `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml`  and `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/fa.xml`   , I could add the new currency to Magento, but in magento 2, even by editing those files, nothing happens.

How can I add this new currency to magento?

Answer (score 1):

This process is a lot more complicated in Magento 2. it doesn't use Zend Currency as in Magento 1, but it uses ICU Data in php compiler.
Take a Look at this project to see how it can be done: https://github.com/aminlatif/Babirusa_Toman

Comment: Can U please help me to add  "POINTS" as my Currency ...

Comment: it doesn't work on 2.3.1 did you find any solution?